# Sort a list of interface objects

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, icomparable

I have a couple of classes that implement an interface, IFoo. I need to display a list of objects of these classes in a table, which I'd like to be able to sort by any arbitrary column in the table. So, the data source for the table is a `List<IFoo>`.

The problem I've run into is that the standard way of implementing `IComparable` or `IComparer` for objects that are used in a list requires a static method, but static methods aren't allowed in interfaces. So, the question boils down to this: how does one sort a `List<IFoo>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**IComparable**

I don't know what gives you the idea that you need to be using a static method, but it's not correct.

You can force all your `IFoo` implementers to implement `IComparable<IFoo>` by adding it to `IFoo`:

```
interface IFoo : IComparable<IFoo> 
{ 
    int Value { get; set; } // for example's sake
}

class SomeFoo : IFoo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(IFoo other)
    {
        // implement your custom comparison here...

        return Value.CompareTo(other.Value); // e.g.
    }
}
```

Then simply sort your `List<IFoo>` like so:

```
list.Sort();
```

**Sorting by an arbitrary column**

You initially stated you want to sort by an arbitrary column in a table of IFoo objects. This is more complex; you need to be able to sort a list of objects by any one of their public properties, so the basic `IComparable<IFoo>` implementation above isn't going to cut it.

The solution is to create a `PropertyComparer<T>` class which implements `IComparer<T>`, and will sort by *any property of* `T`. You could write it specifically for `IFoo`, but at some point every developer tends to come up against this problem and ends up writing a generic property compararer that will try to sort any type. As a result you can google "c# property comparer" and you're sure to get several hits. Here's a simple one:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16200/Simple-PropertyComparer

Comment: This works well, since sorting by an arbitrary column is a requirement. It also encapsulates the sort quite well, which makes for more readable code. Having a generic property comparer is quite useful for other purposes as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what problem you are running into because I just ran a quick test and could sort a list of IFoo. See below for how I did this. If this does not fit your need, could you maybe give more detail?

```
var fooList = new List<IFoo>{new testFoo{key=3}, new testFoo{key=1}};
fooList.Sort(
    delegate(IFoo obj1, IFoo obj2){return obj1.key.CompareTo(obj2.key);});
```

Interface and Concrete

```
public interface IFoo
{
     int key{get;set;}
}

public class testFoo:IFoo
{
    public int key {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# 3/4, you can use a lambda expression..

This example shows how you can sort by different properties of the IFoo interface:

```
void Main()
{
    List<IFoo> foos = new List<IFoo>
    {
        new Bar2{ Name = "Pqr", Price = 789.15m, SomeNumber = 3 },
        new Bar2{ Name = "Jkl", Price = 444.25m, SomeNumber = 1 },
        new Bar1{ Name = "Def", Price = 222.5m, SomeDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Bar1{ Name = "Ghi", Price = 111.1m, SomeDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Bar1{ Name = "Abc", Price = 123.45m, SomeDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Bar2{ Name = "Mno", Price = 564.33m, SomeNumber = 2 }

    };

    foos.Sort((x,y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
    foreach(IFoo foo in foos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
    }

    foos.Sort((x,y) => x.Price.CompareTo(y.Price));
    foreach(IFoo foo in foos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Price);
    }
}

interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
}

class Bar1 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}

class Bar2 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Abc
Def
Ghi
Jkl
Mno
Pqr
111.1
222.5
333.33
444.25
555.45
666.15
```