# Sorting list of interface reference objects inherting ICompareable<T>

Tags: c#, sorting, interface, compareto, icomparable

I was having trouble with list.Sort() for a list of interface references that point to different types however the question [Sort a list of interface objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502240/sort-a-list-of-interface-objects) provided the following solution solution

```
interface IFoo : IComparable<IFoo> 
{ 
    int Value { get; set; } 
}

class SomeFoo : IFoo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(IFoo other)
    {
        // implement your custom comparison here...
    }
}
```

In my original code rather than IFoo inherting from IComparable my class was inherting from both IFoo and ICompareable i.e.

```
interface IFoo
{ 
    int Value { get; set; } 
}

class SomeFoo : IFoo, IComparable<IFoo> 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(IFoo other)
    {
        // implement your custom comparison here...

    }
}
class SomeBar : IFoo, IComparable<IFoo> 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(IFoo other)
    {
        // implement your custom comparison here...
    }
}
```

But I was getting the error `Failed to compare two elements in the array.` when trying to sort a list of IFoo references.

```
List<IFoo> iFoos = new List<IFoo> 
{
    new SomeFoo{Value = 1},
    new SomeFoo{Value = 15},
    new SomeFoo{Value = 390},
    new SomeBar{Value = 2},
    new SomeBar{Value = 78},
    new SomeBar{Value = 134}
}

iFoos.Sort();
```

Can anyone explain why my original code did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is a list of `IFoo`s. So from the perspective of the list (and its sort operation), it only sees that interface and does not know anything about the concrete types.

So when it tries to order two `IFoo`s, it cannot do that because `IFoo` does not implement `IComparable`.

The problem is that just because both your types implement `IComparable<Foo>` separately, there is no guarantee that *all* `IFoo` elements in the list do so. So the operation is not safe.

In order to be able to sort the elements using `IComparable<IFoo>`, the `IFoo` interface needs to implement the interface itself.

---

Alternatively, you could also implement a `IComparer<IFoo>` and pass that to `Sort()` which then delegates to the respective actual implementation. Of course, this is not really an elegant solution and not very future proof (if you ever create a new implementation of `IFoo`):

```
class FooComparer : IComparer<IFoo>
{
    public int Compare(IFoo a, IFoo b)
    {
        if (a is SomeFoo)
            return ((SomeFoo)a).CompareTo(b);
        else if (a is SomeBar)
            return ((SomeBar)a).CompareTo(b);
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException("Comparing neither SomeFoo nor SomeBar");
    }
}
```

Of course, if you mean `IFoo` to be comparable, you should have that interface implement `IComparable<IFoo>` directly instead of relying on subtypes to do so. `IFoo` is a contract, and being sortable is a fine property to require.

Comment: I tried to run it, and you are correct, now the interesting part is that even if you declare the list as `List<IComparable<IFoo>> iFoos = new List<IComparable<IFoo>>()` same exception is thrown. Why would that be?

Comment: @pijemcolu Because now, you have a list of `IComparable<IFoo>`; so in order to compare those objects now, it looks for `IComparable<IComparable<IFoo>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question with a twist!

When you are sorting a type, you expect the type to implement IComparable.

In your original code you are sorting `IFoo` which does not implement `IComparable` but in the second one it does. And that has made all the difference.

But if you had a collection of `List<SomeBar>` it would sort because it has IComparable implemented. Ignoring that you probably would need to use an interface of List I suggest you to use your second solution.

Comment: I think it's just clicked, if my classes `SomeFoo` and `SomeBar` implement `ICompareable` I could sort a list of `SomeFoo` or a list of `SomeBar` but because my interface `IFoo` doesn't implement `ICompareable` a list of `IFoo` can't be sorted?

Comment: Exactly, thats the problem. You got it.

Comment: @JackBlackmore Yes, indeed. The compiler will infer the interface type (read transform `SomeFoo` to `(IFoo)SomeFoo`), so the list will effectively contains ONLY interfaces; not derived instances. As your interface doesn't implement IComparable, the program can't know how to compare different implementations of it.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx):

> This method uses the default comparer `Comparer<T>.Default` for type T
>   to determine the order of list elements. The `Comparer<T>.Default`
>   property checks whether type T implements the IComparable generic
>   interface and uses that implementation, if available. If not,
>   Comparer.Default checks whether type T implements the IComparable
>   interface. If type T does not implement either interface,
>   Comparer.Default throws an InvalidOperationException.

Since `T` is `IFoo`, your first example works when `IFoo` implements `IComparable<IFoo>` and the second fails because it does not. I suggest you create a class `FooComparer : IComparer<Foo>` and pass that to the [other overload of Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Lee, I really need to start getting my head around how the documentation is worded. It's hard to follow but it really is all there!

Answer (score 0):

In your first example `IFoo` implements `IComparable<IFoo>` and in the second one does not. And if you use `Array.Sort` or any other sort routine it will cause an `ArgumentException` that at least one object should implement `IComparable`.